# Spring error when parameter added to bean configuration

Tags: spring, annotations

I am using `Spring` and `Spring` `Annotations` to configure service layer:

Below code works fine:

```
@Configuration
public class AccountServices {
    @Bean
    public List<String> getSourceAccountsList() { //Do something }
```

But as soon as I change the `Bean` configuration method to take the string parameter (below code), I get error.

```
@Configuration
public class AccountServices {
    @Bean
    public List<String> getSourceAccountsList(String userId) { //Do something }
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'getSourceAccountsList' defined in class path resource [net/iranet/isc/saba/services/AccountServices.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using service correctly? why you don't annot service as `@Service`? The method `getSourceAccountsList` seems a method you need to call from somewhere else and parameter is provided from the caller, not the configuration itself

Comment: Yes the service is called from web controller (struts action). I found that "right now spring 3.2.4"@Service annotation does not do any thing more than component. But I will use @Service because they say that it may change in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using `@Bean` in a wrong way, especially in `@Service` layer (and usually `@Bean` method doesn't have a get, but only , in your case sourceAccountsList()).
 Who provide the `userId` parameter, the web controller?

If `AccountService` is called from a controller you have something like (pseudo-code):

```
@Service
public class AccountServices {
  public List<String> getAccountService(String userId) {
    // Retrieve List<String> from database, or file, or somewhere else via DAO
    // directly
  }
}

@Controller
public class Controller {
  @Autowired
  private AccountsService accountService;

  public void doAction(Request request) {
    String userId = request.getParameter("userId");

    request.putParameter("accountsList",this.accountService.getSourceAccountsList(userId));
    forwardTo("/newPage.jsp", request);
  }
}
```

Read about controller/service/repository in Spring means ([Google search](https://www.google.it/search?q=spring+using+service+repository&rlz=1C1SVEC_enIT386&oq=spring+using+service+repository&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i62l3.29048j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=352c98cb4de796a&q=spring+using+service+repository+controller&safe=off) with a lot of resource) and from [SpringSource](http://www.springsource.org/).
After you understand layer separation you can add `@Transaction` management (for example) and all other feature you need.

Comment: You saved me! thanks. One more help. 
I expected that the Controller class should have a AccountServices accountServices. 
So the spring could use it to inject the AccountService in the controller. I am running a sample projects but every things works without to have and setAccountService(AccountServices accountServices)...

Comment: Most probably due to autowiring (@Autowired annotation), but my advice is to read official documentation about Spring's annotations

Answer (score 0):

When you use @Configuration and @Bean annotations you configure beans, parameters for methods annotated with @Bean are threated as references to another beans, so you should add bean with class String and probably name of bean "userId" - name of parameter used for autowire by name.

Comment: can u please let me know how should i do it with annotation !

Comment: You should declare one more method with @Bean annotation and with return type String

Comment: You mean some thing like String setUserId(String userID) and make getSourceAccountsList() use that! I am very new in using Spring

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. I think you are trying to use `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations in some strange way - may be not for configuring beans.

Comment: Yeah, I think the same

Comment: :) Well let me ask again! The service layer has a method which get an string as parameter (userId) and returns the list of user bank accounts. The service layer bean is managed by spring. And I want to use spring annotation. I come to the problem that I can not use String parameter directly !! Now please let me know is it an strange case, our how should I configure this service in Spring!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: the `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations must not be used to define services. They're used to configure beans in the container, as a replacement to the Spring context XML files. Your class should be annotated with `@Service`, and your method shouldn't be annotated at all.